# Ruby on Rails robots.txt folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, robots.txt

I'm about to launch a Ruby on Rails application and as the last task, I want to set the *robots.txt* file. I couldn't find information about how the paths should be written properly for a Rails application.

Is the starting path always the root path from the Ruby on Rails application or the app folder? How would I then disallow, e.g., the *img* folder?

Do I have to write the paths as I see them in the *app* folder, or like how the paths look on the site online, e.g. http://example.com/admin?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to put your *robots.txt* file in the `/public` folder.

It may look like this example from [robotstxt.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20071002042544/http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/norobots.html):

> The following example "/robots.txt" file specifies that no robots should visit any URL starting with "/cyberworld/map/" or "/tmp/", or /foo.html:
>
> ```
> # robots.txt for http://www.example.com/
>
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /cyberworld/map/ # This is an infinite virtual URL space
> Disallow: /tmp/ # these will soon disappear
> Disallow: /foo.html
> ```

Further reading:

- *[How Google interprets the robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)*
- *[About /robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)*

Answer (score 3):

Ruby on Rails automatically creates a `public/robots.txt` by default since at least Ruby on Rails 3 or even earlier. All files in `public/*` will be delivered by Puma/Thin/Webrick/Passenger by default, so it is just enough to put the file there.

Inside you can just disallow specific paths by writing the absolute path beginning with "/":

```
User-agent: *
Disallow /img
```

See the [Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#search-engines-indexing) for more information on *robots.txt*.